# Is set $S$ with these operations a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Consider a set $S=\{a,b\}$ with addition and multiplication defined by:
>   $$\begin{align*}
> a+a&=a& a+b&=b& b+a&=b& b+b&=a\\
> a\times a&=a& a\times b&=a& b\times a&=a& b\times b&=b
> \end{align*}$$
>
> Is $S$ a ring?

If it is a ring since addition and multiplication that would be done are all in the sets itself would that be the correct answer?

Comment: It is obviously isomorphic to $GF(2)$, the Galois field of two elements. A field is of course a ring.

Comment: What is a ring?

Comment: You could simply give $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as an example rather than $GF(2)$. The OP is clearly a beginner in ring theory, he mostly doesn't know what a field is and what a Galois field stands for ;)

Comment: @miracle173: If you've seen "groups", then rings are a natural next thing to learn -- a generalization of things that have nice addition and multiplication (but not necessarily division), like polynomials. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)

Comment: @AlexMeiburg Thx, but this was a hint for the OP that he should proceed by describing the properties of a ring.

Comment: @miracle173 Oh man xD I'm sorry. I assumed you were a novice asking out of curiosity... should've checked your profile first. My bad haha

Answer (score 5):

The most straightforward to verify that it is a ring is to interpret "a" as "0", and "b" as "1". Then S has the ring structure of the integers, mod 2.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming multiplication is associative, but might not be commutative or have an identity, there are only two rings with two elements. These are $\mathbb{F}_2 = \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$, and $\{0,1\}$ where addition is mod $2$ and multiplication always returns $0$.

So, you just have to check if the addition and multiplication tables match either of these two rings. As others have observed, you should quickly see it matches $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Answer (score 0):

> If it is a ring since addition and multiplication that would be done are all in the sets itself would that be the correct answer?

No, the set being closed under addition ("being all in the set itself") is *not* sufficient for it being a ring. It is,of course, necessary (so if it were not the case, it couldn't be a ring).

To check that you have a ring,you have to check that *all* the ring axioms are fulfilled. Of course, as the other answers mentioned, you can shortcut the tests by mapping to structures you already know to have the desired property.

So if you already know that $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is a ring, it is sufficient to show that you can identify $a$ and $b$ with $0$ and $1$ and obtain $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. If you only know that $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is a group under addition, you can use that identification, too, but still need to prove the ring properties involving multiplication.